# SQL Server 2005 query issues

Tags: sql-server-2005

Suppose I have a table like this..

```
ColA    ColB    ColC
----------------------
A       100     1
A       200     2
A       300     3
B       100     1
B       200     2
C       300     1
```

I have to select COLA where 100=1 and 200=2 and 300=3

Please help

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your desired output?

Comment: What results set are you wanting as the question isn't very clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I could understand from your question, you need somthing simple like:

```
select COLA where ( (COLB=100 and COLC=1) or (COLB=200 and COLC=2) or (COLB=300 and COLC=3) )
```

or go for the more general:

```
select COLA where COLB = COLC*100
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT ColA
FROM   my_table
WHERE  ColB = (ColC * 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to handle that, but this is probably the simplest, and will perform quite decently given your alternatives:

```
SELECT ColA
FROM  MyTable
WHERE (ColB = 100 AND ColC = 1)
OR (ColB = 200 AND ColC = 2)
OR (ColB = 300 AND ColC = 3)
GROUP BY ColA
HAVING COUNT(*) = 3
```

Comment: It is fine without the group by clause

Thank you very much